# Why Wordpress gets old templates code instead of the last updated ones

Tags: theme-development, page-template, child-theme

I recently finished building my WP theme (child theme of twentyfifteen). 
My friend started updating content and accidentally added content to a page which don't have a function that gets and displays the content.

From since, everytime we update the template.php file - we cant see any changes on the website, moreover, we see a very old version of the website. We compared the HTML code from  the website with the on in the last updated PHP file and it's still uses the old HTML - We totally deleted the .php file of the template - and the page is still displayed!!!

We restarted the server, we deleted all tables in the database using a plugin, and nothing!

I started adding all pages and templates (because all the DB is deleted..), elements suddenly look strange. I changed the templates name from "Homepage Template" to "NEW Homepage Template" and I get the templates in addition to the old strange templates in the template list.

[image]

What is happening with my website? 
How do I stop it?

Comment: I'm confused, are you saying that the PHP file on your file system is the old version? Can you simplify your english? I'm also very confused by this: "My friend started updating content and accidentally added content to a page which don't have a function that gets and displays the content." how is this relevant to your question?

Comment: Also, you're aware there is a `home.php` theme template? You do not need a page template to create a homepage template

Comment: It sounds like the child theme is getting the parent theme template for some reason. This is most likely due to a spelling error on a child template or something similar.

Also, if that isn't it, try and be more specific as to what exact template file is being used, what you expect to happen, and what you see happening. Good Luck. :)